# Convert Model into a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, viewmodel

I have a model for my table OWNER

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public partial class Owner
    {
        public int owner_id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then i have my ViewModel

```
public partial class OwnerData
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Create the object Owner based on the User Identity
        Owner owner = CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntity(User, db).Owner;

//New instance of the ViewModel
        OwnerData ownerData = new OwnerData();

        ownerData.lastname = owner.lastname;
        ownerData.firstname = owner.firstname;
        ownerData.address = owner.address;

            return View(ownerData);

    }
```

There's a simpler way in order to convert my `owner` into `ownerData` without rewrite evry single property of my object?

Comment: there is a way but it's not simple for sure.keep this way

Comment: There are tools that use "Reflection" and do this for you by matching properties names. I would keep this way for now, but would add a constructor in the OwnerData that accepts Owner object and does this.

Comment: @A Khudairy I think i found a good solution using **Automapper** by doing **Mapper.CreateMap<Owner, OwnerData>();** and then **OwnerData ownerData = Mapper.Map<Owner, OwnerData>(CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntity(User, db).Owner);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i solved the problem using `Automapper`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Create the object Owner based on the User Identity
    Owner owner = CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntity(User, db).Owner;

    Mapper.CreateMap<Owner, OwnerData>();
    OwnerData ownerData = Mapper.Map<Owner, OwnerData>(owner);

  return View(ownerData);
}
```

Or if you prefer a dynamic function

```
    static TDestination GenerateMappingTable<TSource, TDestination>(TSource inputModel)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
        return Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(inputModel);
    }
```

To install Automapper just execute

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper
```

from the package manager console.

Comment: Mapper.CreateMap call should once per app domain. We should call it in Application_Start() method. Otherwise it will be called whenever Index() is called

Answer (score 1):

You can use [object initizalizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).That makes it more simple,but I'm not sure this is what you want

```
OwnerData ownerData = new OwnerData  { 
                          lastname = owner.lastname;
                          firstname = owner.firstname;
                          address = owner.address;
                          };
```

Comment: Better to edit the constructor Instead of doing this each time you need it.